# RadiobuttonList post-back to Index 0

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

On selection of any radiobuttons or form events that trigger a post-back my radiobuttonlist selections goto Index 0.  None of the other form items are affected.  I have disabled Master List redirect code, I have made an entirely new page with nothing in it except a dropdownlist, radiobuttonlist, and labels to view selected data.  I am stumped.

Any advise?  I just want it to keep the selectedindex and allow me to populate the correct value between post backs.

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="s_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder_menuBar" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder_userBar" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder_mainActivityWindow" Runat="Server">
<form id="Form1" runat="server">
    <p>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_Shift1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="true">
            <asp:ListItem Text="d" Value="d" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="n" Value="n" Selected="False"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="h" Value="h" Selected="False"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </p>
    <p>
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbl_C112" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="true">
            <asp:ListItem Text="2" Value="112" Selected="False" ></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="3" Value="112" Selected="False" ></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="4" Value="112" Selected="False" ></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="5" Value="112" Selected="False" ></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Unassigned" Value="112" Selected="True" ></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
    </p>    
    <p>
        <asp:Label ID="l_c112" Text="" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="username" Text="" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </p>
    </form>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content5" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder_tutorialBar" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content6" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder_foot" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
```

VB Codebehind s_Default

```
Partial Class s_Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Sub Page_Load() Handles Me.Load
        username.Text = Session("UserRole").ToString()
    End Sub

    Protected Sub rbl_C112_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles rbl_C112.SelectedIndexChanged
        l_c112.Text = ""
        l_c112.Text = rbl_C112.SelectedItem.ToString()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not the selected index which is returned after post-back, its the selected value.

As `rbl_C112` all have the same values (`112`), its going to select the first 1 which matches the value.

Change the values of your DropDownList options so that they are unique and this will resolve your issue.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbl_C112" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="true">
       <asp:ListItem Text="2" Value="112" Selected="False" ></asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Text="3" Value="113" Selected="False" ></asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Text="4" Value="114" Selected="False" ></asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Text="5" Value="115" Selected="False" ></asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Text="Unassigned" Value="116" Selected="True" ></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is due to several of those list items having the exact same value, on postback it uses the select value to set the item, if as you have:

```
 <asp:ListItem Text="2" Value="112" Selected="False" ></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="3" Value="112" Selected="False" ></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="4" Value="112" Selected="False" ></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="5" Value="112" Selected="False" ></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Unassigned" Value="112" Selected="True" ></asp:ListItem>
```

Then if you select 5, then postback then it will set 2 as that is the first item in the list with the value you selected.